# Issues mounting NFS share on client

Tags: linux, linux-networking, nfs

I'm kind of new to working with NFS shares, but here's what I have.

### Server:

#### /etc/hosts.allow:

```
ALL: client1.mydomain.com, client2.mydomain.com
```

#### /etc/hosts.deny:

```
portmap:ALL
lockd:ALL
mountd:All
rquotad:ALL
statd:ALL
```

#### /etc/exports:

```
/mnt/storage client1.mydomain.com(rw) client2.mydomain.com(rw)
/mnt/logs client1.mydomain.com(rw) client2.mydomain.com(rw)
```

On a client computer, I run the following:

```
mount server1.mydomain.com:/mnt/storage /mnt/storage
```

It hangs for a *very* long time, then fails with:

```
mount.nfs: Input/output error
```

What's the problem here, how can I tell what's going wrong?

Comment: can you add the output of 'showmount -e servername' on the client?

Comment: Just a thought, but the URIs can be successfully resolved to IP addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed simply to run `portmapper` on each client before trying to mount. Weird. I would assume that the `mount.nfs` command would know to do that, but it apparently doesn't.